# How to Put Graph Using Drawing?

Tags: iphone

I Want to Put a Line with Static x,y Co-ordinates but i want to vary the height accoding to some conditions

```
-(void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    AppDelegate *delegate = (AppDelegate *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
    CGRect customPath1 = CGRectMake(35, 183, 10, delegate.breakFastTotalamt);
    CGRect customPath2 = CGRectMake(140, 183, 10, 100);
    UIBezierPath *path1 = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:customPath1];
     UIBezierPath *path2 = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:customPath2];
    [[UIColor greenColor]set];
    [path1 fill];
    [path2 fill];
}
```

Comment: So, what's the question?

Comment: Also, I only see two rectangles in your code but no line nor height.

Comment: I AM PUTTING A HORIZONTAL LINE CREATED BY BUTTON BY MAKINT ITS WIDTH 2. ON THAT LINE I WANT TO PUT A VARTICAL LINE USING UIBEZIERPATH. I AM GETTING HEIGHT VALUES FROM DATABASE. WHEN THE HEIGHT VARIES THE LINE GOING ABOUT THAT BUTTON.I WANT STARTING POINT TO BE STATIC ONLY HEIGHT SHOULD VARY

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To draw a vertical line starting from (x,y) and with a height h, you can do something like this:

```
UIBezierPath*    path = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
[path moveToPoint:CGPointMake(x, y)];
[path addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(x, y + h)];
[path closePath];
[[UIColor greenColor] setStroke];
path.lineWidth = 5; // Or whatever width you want
[path stroke];
```